# Kotlin: Try, catch, and only finally if error

Tags: kotlin, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I have a block of code which can throw & catch errors like so

```kotlin
try {

} catch (e: FooException) {

} catch (e: BarException) {

} finally {

}
```

and have some code which only needs to run if *at least one error* was caught, perhaps by some imaginary `catchfinally` block. Other than storing an `errorCaught` variable and checking it in `finally`, is there a more readable alternative?

Comment: Put the code in a function and call it on each catch instead. Another option is let the exceptions transfer to the caller and handle the error there.

Comment: Put the whole block in a function, and use a `return`at the end of the `try { … }` block?  Or put it all in a `do { … } while (false)` and use a `break`?

Comment: If you don't distinguish between the exceptions in the handling at all you may also just `catch(e: Exception)`. If you do, put the common code in a function and call it from the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `finally` is to execute a block of code regardless of any exception to be thrown or not. imho, it should be used like that for better readability. A generic `catch` block is best suitable for your use case rather than a `finally` block. I would suggest doing the following thing.

Put your code in a function, remove the `finally` block, and throw the exception from individual catch block

```
fun newMethod() {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (e: FooException) {
        // do something
        throw e
    } catch (e: BarException) {
        // do something
        throw e
    }
}
```

From the caller, have a generic `catch` block

```
try {
    newMethod()
} catch {
    // execute code that wanted to execute for any exception
}
```

From a separate place, if you need to have a finally block, you can implement it there.

```
try {
    newMethod()
} catch {
    // do something
} finally {
    // finally block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an option is to flag a variable at the *end* of the `try` block, and check for its state in `finally`

```kotlin
var errorThrown = true
try {
    // ... all code (no return statements) ...
    errorThrown = false
} catch (e: FooException) {

} catch (e: BarException) {

} finally {
    if (errorThrown) {
        // run if at least one error
    }
}
```

This looks to me like it requires minimal additional code, compared to adding some code / function call inside every single `catch`